# Trying to Properly configure the mod alias in Apache

Tags: apache, mod-alias

I'm running apache 2.2.24 on Max OS X 10.9.1.  Currently, we have a network drive that we access all of our Git repos on at /Volumes/GitWebsites.  I would like to configure Apache to serve our PHP based repos from that directory.  So, localhost (or 127.0.0.1)/phpsite1/ or /phpsite2? etc. will serve sites from /Volumes/GitWebsites/phpsite1/ or /phpsite2/ in the browser.  My two questions are:

1. Do I simply modify the server root or do I need to use the mod-alias in the httpd.conf file?
2. What are the permission setting I need to in order for apache to access /Volumes/GitWebsites ?

I've done configuration changes like this in IIS 7.5 and set up a NodeJS dev environment but still new to make large scale changes to Apache.  Thanks for any help given.

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy with serving the contents of `/Volumes/GitWebsites` as it is then it should be fine to point the document root at it. It's also makes it easy to add sites later.
However this could be troublesome later if you want to manage php configuration later on for the sites separately.